# How do I access my json data that I have created in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

What url can I enter to see the json value and how do I get my iphone project to access it.

Here is my index method

```
def index
        @players = Player.find(:all)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json  { render :json => @players.to_json }
        end
    end
```

here is my routes.

```
ChooseTeams::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :players
 root :to => "players#index"
end
```

Please ask for any additional information as I'm new in rails and not sure what else to provide here.

Answer (score 4):

to index method: localhost:(port)/players.json
(Method GET)

to show method: localhost:(port)/players/1.json
(Method GET)

I recomend to you POSTMAN(in Google Chrome) to test this respond.

To respond to iPhone JSON use REST API

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

Answer (score 0):

You should set the accept headers when requesting the URL:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:<PORT>/players
```

In your iOS project, you should set whatever HTTP library you're using to set the above header.